# Why my __proto__ reference shows wrong name in console?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

My **proto** reference of "mike" instance  points to "Student" but as its name shows "Person" , I don't know why is that. Here is my code and screenshot of console below:

```js
const Person = function (firstName,birthYear) {
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.birthYear = birthYear;
}

Person.prototype.calcAge = function () {
   console.log(2037 - this.birthYear);
}


const Student = function (firstName, birthYear, course){
   Person.call(this,firstName,birthYear);
   this.course = course;
};


Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype)

Student.prototype.constructor = Student;

Student.prototype.introduce = function () {
   console.log(`My name is ${this.firstName} and ,I study ${this.course}`);
}

const mike = new Student('Mike',2020, 'Computer Science');

console.log(mike);
```

When I check on console it shows Person:

[image: Console Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype)`
In this case, you are creating a new object and make it the value of `Student.prototype`. The new object `Student` has `Person.prototype` as its prototype.

Answer (score 1):

The very first thing you see in Chrome's console is `Student`. That is the "type" of your `mike` object.

On the other hand, the `__proto__` property of `mike` references the prototype from which this instance was created. Your code has explicitly defined that prototype with the following statement:

```
Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

So, from that moment on, `Student.prototype instanceof Person` is true, but `Student.prototype instanceof Student` false. And all instances created with `new Student`, will reference the `Student.prototype` in their `__proto__` property. So what you see is as expected.

The fact that the following assignment was made, doesn't change this behaviour:

```
Student.prototype.constructor = Student;
```

This is a cosmetic change, and doesn't determine the nature of the instances that `Student` creates. That might have mislead you.

### class syntax

The code you provided performs the steps needed to set up a prototype chain, where a `Student` inherits from a `Person`.

In modern JavaScript it is much less cryptical to make this happen. Nowadays you would write this example as follows:

```js
class Person {
    constructor(firstName,birthYear) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.birthYear = birthYear;
    }
    calcAge() {
        console.log(2037 - this.birthYear);
    }
}

class Student extends Person {
    constructor(firstName, birthYear, course) {
        super(birthYear, course);
        this.course = course;
    }
    introduce() {
         console.log(`My name is ${this.firstName} and ,I study ${this.course}`);
    }
}

const mike = new Student('Mike',2020, 'Computer Science');

console.log(mike);
```

The result in the console will also here confirm that the prototype object of a `Student` instance is an instance of `Person` (not of `Student`).